# Hadoop MapReduce one output for each input

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm currently working on a MapReduce project, and I need to analyze many text files in a given input directory, and I need to separate each result in a different file depending on the input file name
ex :

```
input/
  file01.txt
  file02.txt
  file03.txt
  file04.txt
```

I'll need to have

```
output/
  file01.txt
  file02.txt
  file03.txt
  file04.txt
```

I've seen a few questions about this but can't seem to make anything work (using hadoop 2.6)
(ps: not using yarn)

Thanks

Comment: just map output or mapreduce output per input file?

Comment: mapreduce output per input file

Comment: Then i would suggest you write a script and run map red multiple times.

Comment: What is the analysis?

Comment: @Jeremy I'm just counting the occurences of each letter in the text (to later determine the language of the text)

Comment: @SMA Now wondering why I didn't think of that sooner, is there a way to specify the output file name instead of the part-r-0000 I have ? (Running on single cluster node)

Comment: have a look at [this](http://johnnyprogrammer.blogspot.in/2012/01/custom-file-output-in-hadoop.html)

Comment: Anyway to make the output filename match the input filename ? (Not sure I can use a static String in the Main class to store the input name ?)

Comment: Edit: found my way with a custom JobName containing file name. Not sure using 1 job for each file is optimized